# Remove part of a string between characters at the end of the string

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a normal string with a directory set by the user. My goal is to add fuction like cd .. aka "go back a directory" how can I do this? this is an example of what the content is of the string: `c:/test/example/`

I want to change the string to `c:/test/`

I want to remove the final sub-directory.

As I said before, I cant just remove "example/" from the string. It's defined by the user and the length can vary.

Comment: Find the location of the last `/` that _isn't_ the last character in the string or the first `/` in the string. Remove everything after it. Have you tried anything? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`System.IO.Directory.GetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=net-5.0):

```
DirectoryInfo parentDir = Directory.GetParent("c:/test/example/");
string result = parentDir.Parent.FullName;
```

I guess you need to handle the case that there is no `/` or `\` at the end:

```
string path = "c:/test/example";
path = path.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) ? path : path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Path.GetDirectoryName` on a path that nominates a folder (it's not just for use on files)

The trailing slash may need trimming off first; you'd probably be better off working with/ensuring you only have paths that *don't* end in directory separator chars, and use `Path.Combine` to build paths

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to remove the last dir of any path by using *Substring()* and *LastIndexOf()*, Ex:

```
var path = "c:/test/example/dir/anotherdir/deepdir";

path = path.Substring(0, path.Trim('/').LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Output:

```
c:/test/example/dir/anotherdir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int position = 0;
        string dir = "c:/test/example/";

        for (int i = dir.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (dir.Substring(i - 1, 1) == "/")
            {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dir.Substring(0, position));
```